# How can I use HTTP POST data on nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Google Cloud Function and want to process the data provided by the post request.

**On the website**:

```
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url='https://us-central1-finitest-4aafb.cloudfunctions.net/create-user1';
        Http.open("POST", url);
        Http.send("name=Negan&password=Lucille");

        Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
            console.log(Http.responseText)
        }
```

**On the server**:

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');

  let message = 'User created ' + req.body.user;
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

How can I use the "name=Negan&password=Lucille" data on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a POST request with `XMLHttpRequest()`, you need to get the parameters via the body of the request, as follows:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.name);
    console.log(req.body.password);

    let message = 'User created ' + req.body.name;
    res.status(200).send(message);
});
```

More details in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0#read_values_from_the_request).

You also need, on the frontend, to send the proper content-type (i.e. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) along with the request, as follows:

```
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url='https://us-central1-finitest-4aafb.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld';
    Http.open("POST", url);

    // send the proper header information along with the request
    Http.setRequestHeader(
      'Content-type',
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    );

    Http.send("name=Negan&password=Lucille");

    Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
        console.log(Http.responseText)
    }
```

---

If you want to get them as query string parameters, as explained by Ashish Kumar, you need to add them to the URL, not via `send()`, since you use a POST.

```
    const url='https://us-central1-finitest-4aafb.cloudfunctions.net/create-user1';
    Http.open("POST", url + "?name=Negan&password=Lucille");  // Note the ?
    Http.send();
```

In this case you can use `req.query.name`.

More details in the result of this search: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=XMLHttpRequest.send%28%29+POST+querystring

---

Finally, be aware that with `https://us-central1-finitest-4aafb.cloudfunctions.net/create-user1` you are NOT calling your `helloWorld` Cloud Function, but a `create-user1` Cloud Function.

Answer (score 1):

Those are called request query and they can be accessed via `req.query` object.
So in your case you can access the data as

```
req.query.name
req.query.password
```